# SMB Intermittent Time Out on Raspbmc

Tags: networking, raspbmc, macos, samba, share

I am using my Raspberry Pi to stream video and audio content off of my Macbook through an SMB share.  The content will stream perfectly when it works but the SMB connection seems to drop at least once a day, if not more often.  When this happens, the SMB connection repeatedly times out.  Restarting the Pi and the Macbook only works intermittently.  The Pi is wired to the network but the laptop is connected wirelessly.  Any thoughts?

Operating system - OSX 10.9.2

Raspberry operating system - XBMC 12.3

Comment: Why use `SMB`. It is a B of a protocol, and every time you add another connection there is a fight about which is going to be bus master. Use `SMB` if you must communicate with Windows, otherwise use `NFS`.

Comment: I used to have a PC on the network that needed to share/access files but no longer, I'll try to switch to NFS and see if that works.

Comment: Any recommendations for a good guide on setting up NFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this exact same problem using SMB (with a pi as well as without). It was caused by failed hostname resolution issues that were due to conflicting WINS servers on the network.

Solution was to connect via IP instead of hostname.

Comment: I've only had this set up for a day or two but it certainly seems to be the answer! No connection drops so far.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help you out @Vinnie. Hopefully the SMB connection stays up and running now you're connecting directly via IP :)